# Display percentage value as a fill in a custom shape

Tags: analytics, data-visualization

I'm looking at some new options for displaying a percentage value as a fill in a custom shape. Consider the effect to be similar to a "progress thermometer" in a traditional dashboard UI sense.

### Considerations

- Goal - a graphic element showing a percentage value for a custom report.
- Format - Either a full graphic (or infographic) itself, or part of a PDF via Photoshop/InDesign or even iBooks (as an excuse to use it).
- Usage - I'd like the process to be programmatic, for re-use. It needs to be accurate, and I'd like the solution to be somewhat object oriented to apply to other datasets and graphical containers. This rules out hand-drawn charting.
- Source data - currently a pivot table in Excel, but I can work with any other host as required.
- Shape - is a custom vector shape that will originate from Illustrator/Inkscape. final format as best fits resolution and rendering of the report. I would also be interested in any other generative shape ideas (such as java/javascript).
- Fill - I'd like to be able to represent the fill as both an actual percentage of total area (true up), and as a percentage of the vertical scale. I'd imagine this flexibility would also help reuse of the method as a fill value against selected object variables (height, area, whatever).

I know I'm being slightly vague in the programming languages or hosts side of things, but this gives me an opportunity to break out of the usual analytic toolchain and scope out some  innovative or new solutions. I'm specifically interested in open source solutions, but I'm very keen to review other current methods you might suggest.

Comment: The *display* part is straightforward - you just overlay a second vector shape on top of the first that represents the percentage.

The real question here seems to be "given vector shape A, percentage B and attribute C (e.g. height, width, area), calculate a new vector shape D that overlays that percentage of that attribute on shape A"

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little open ended for you, but [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) is very powerful. There might be some useful templates on the site, or you can build your own from the library.

Comment: D3 looks great, and the js side of things seems to be a common factor in a lot of the great visualisation examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you limit yourself to shapes where the percentage can be easily converted into a new shape by varying one of the dimensions, then the display part can be covered by creating a *second* shape based on the first one, and filling in 100% of the second shape.

This obviously works best with simple shapes like squares, rectangles, circles, etc, where it is simple to convert "50% of the area" or "75% of the height" into manipulation of vector nodes.

However, things gets significantly more difficult if you want to support genuinely arbitrary custom shapes. One way to handle that would be to break up a complex "progress bar" into "progress pieces" (e.g. a thermometer bulb that represents 10% of total progress, then a simple bar for the remaining 90%).

Comment: In terms of actual techniques for making these adjustments, one of our designers here recommends using either inline SVG to alter the node data, or a transform matrix that does the same thing.

Comment: Sounds good, although preparing for arbitrary shapes from the outset would put in place some good workflow. As a Python ninja, is there anything Python-specific that might be useful to in interpreting data/numeric values as visual elements? Tools, programs, common libraries or scripts etc?

Comment: Alas, I know very little about graphics programming and data visualisation myself - most of my answer came from asking one of our designers here how he'd do it.

Comment: That said, he did have one specific toolkit recommendation in terms of Web visualisation: http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) seems like it would meet your needs - here are some simple examples of what I think you are asking:

Changing the fill color of a distinct shape: http://jsfiddle.net/jsl6906/YCMb8/

Changing the 'fill amount' of a simple shape: http://jsfiddle.net/jsl6906/YCMb8/1/

Comment: Those are great examples, thanks for sharing. Looks like js is the path I should be focusing on for a while.